# RTP Header C Programming

Tags: c, rtp

I create UDP packets (insert IP and UDP headers) and send across the UDP socket. I want to add a dummy RTP header to the packet that I create. I created the RTP structure and inserting the RTP header as below:

```
rtph->cc = 4
rtph->x = 1
rtph->p = 1
rtph->version = 2
rtph->pt = 7
rtph->m = 1
rtph->seq = 0
rtph->ts = random()
rtph->ssrc = 0
```

When I capture in the wireshasrk I get Unknown RTP Version 3.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You must at least show the declarations you're using, and perhaps even the code where you do the actual sending.

Comment: The RTP version is coded with the 2 first bits of the first byte. If you add the rtph description it will be possible to give an answer. It could be just a field order problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you define your own struct in C for RTP you must take the byte order into account.

```
typedef struct _RTPHeader
{
  //first byte
#if G_BYTE_ORDER == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         CC:4;        /* CC field */
  unsigned int         X:1;         /* X field */
  unsigned int         P:1;         /* padding flag */
  unsigned int         version:2;
#elif G_BYTE_ORDER == G_BIG_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         version:2;
  unsigned int         P:1;         /* padding flag */
  unsigned int         X:1;         /* X field */
  unsigned int         CC:4;        /* CC field*/
#else
#error "G_BYTE_ORDER should be big or little endian."
#endif
  //second byte
#if G_BYTE_ORDER == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         PT:7;     /* PT field */
  unsigned int         M:1;       /* M field */
#elif G_BYTE_ORDER == G_BIG_ENDIAN
  unsigned int         M:1;         /* M field */
  unsigned int         PT:7;       /* PT field */
#else
#error "G_BYTE_ORDER should be big or little endian."
#endif
  guint16              seq_num;      /* length of the recovery */
  guint32              TS;                   /* Timestamp */
  guint32              ssrc;
} RTPHeader; //12 bytes
```

The struct must be 12 bytes long, so you need force the compiler to pack it into a 12bytes long struct and not padding it.
Also I would add a static assert to check at compile time weather the struct really 12 bytes long, so:

```
#ifdef __WIN32__

#define PACKED
#pragma pack(push,1)

#else
#define PACKED __attribute__ ((__packed__))
#endif

//---------------------- STATIC ASSERT ----------------------------------
//Source: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html
#define ASSERT_CONCAT_(a, b) a##b
#define ASSERT_CONCAT(a, b) ASSERT_CONCAT_(a, b)
/* These can't be used after statements in c89. */
#ifdef __COUNTER__
#define STATIC_ASSERT(e,m) \
    ;enum { ASSERT_CONCAT(static_assert_, __COUNTER__) = 1/(!!(e)) }
#else
  /* This can't be used twice on the same line so ensure if using in headers
   * that the headers are not included twice (by wrapping in #ifndef...#endif)
   * Note it doesn't cause an issue when used on same line of separate modules
   * compiled with gcc -combine -fwhole-program.  */
#define STATIC_ASSERT(e,m) \
    ;enum { ASSERT_CONCAT(assert_line_, __LINE__) = 1/(!!(e)) }
#endif

typedef struct _RTPHeader
    {
      //first byte
    #if G_BYTE_ORDER == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
      unsigned int         CC:4;        /* CC field */
      unsigned int         X:1;         /* X field */
      unsigned int         P:1;         /* padding flag */
      unsigned int         version:2;
    #elif G_BYTE_ORDER == G_BIG_ENDIAN
      unsigned int         version:2;
      unsigned int         P:1;         /* padding flag */
      unsigned int         X:1;         /* X field */
      unsigned int         CC:4;        /* CC field*/
    #else
    #error "G_BYTE_ORDER should be big or little endian."
    #endif
      //second byte
    #if G_BYTE_ORDER == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
      unsigned int         PT:7;     /* PT field */
      unsigned int         M:1;       /* M field */
    #elif G_BYTE_ORDER == G_BIG_ENDIAN
      unsigned int         M:1;         /* M field */
      unsigned int         PT:7;       /* PT field */
    #else
    #error "G_BYTE_ORDER should be big or little endian."
    #endif
      guint16              seq_num;      /* length of the recovery */
      guint32              TS;                   /* Timestamp */
      guint32              ssrc;
    } RTPHeader; //12 bytes

STATIC_ASSERT (sizeof (RTPHeader) == 12, "RTPHeader size doesn't seem to be cool.");

#ifdef __WIN32__
#pragma pack(pop)
#undef PACKED

#else
#undef PACKED
#endif
```

The version number must be 2 and then if you write to the bytes with this struct, like this:

```
char buffer[1400];
RTPHeader *rtph = (RTPHeader*) buffer;
rtph->version = 2;
```

then theoretically it would be ok.

Comment: I tried this structure definition and it doesn't work on Windows. To fix it, modify the bites fields type to unsigned char! I hope it will help somebody! Thank you!

Comment: @IvanDubynets, thanks for the comment, you are right, int is 4 byte, we need 1 for the CC,X,PT,version, and one for PT, and M. sorry for the inconvenience, my guess why it worked for me at that time is the compile specific flag, which squezed and packed the bytes together.